# C makefile produce only 1 out file instead of 2

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have the files `bar.c` & `foo.c` in the same folder.

And I have the following makefile:

```
foo: foo.c
     gcc -o foo foo.c

all: clean foo bar

bar: bar.c
     gcc -o bar bar.c

clean:
     rm -rf bar foo
```

The output is `foo` only, and the question is why? What's the difference between `foo` & `bar`?

Comment: Are you just running `make`? The default target (the first one) is `foo`, which will only result in one file. Try `make all` or `make foo bar`. Or moving `all` to the top of the file.

Comment: (OT: Having `clean` as a prerequisite for `all` is unconventional. One of the main features of make is that it doesn’t run things that don’t need to run if the results will be the same. Always cleaning before compiling defeats that.)

Comment: @Biffen yes I'm only running 'make' - is the default target is always the first one in the makefile?

Comment: Yes. `all` is not a magic name, just a convention.

Comment: @Biffen OK I think I got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you run it as `make`. By default make processes first target in the makefile, which is "foo". Place target "all" first, and you'll get both "foo" and "bar". Another way is to explicitly specify target, i.e. run `make all` instead of just `make`.